# Can't get substring from strings. Help needed

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column that contains string like

```
'ID=1,Name=GDNDL380F4,Type=FTT-87, Value=GDNDL380F4,Registration Info: Sn = GDNDL380F4, Service Level=Service Level Disabled'

|Column               
|'ID=1,Name=GDNDL380F4,Type=FTT-87, Value=GDNDL380F4,Registration Info: Sn = GDNDL380F4, Service Level=Service Level Disabled'|  
|'ID=1,Name=GDNDL4040F4,Type=FTT-87, Value=GDNDL4040F4,Registration Info: Sn = GDNDL380F4, Service Level=Service Level Disabled'|  
|'ID=1,Name=GDNDL380F5,Type=FTT-87, Value=GDNDL380F5,Registration Info: Sn = GDNDL380F4, Service Level=Service Level Disabled'|
```

Expected Output:

```
Name       |  Type  |  
GDNDL380F4 |FTT-87  |  
GDNDL4040F4|FTT-87  | 
GDNDL380F5 |FTT-87  |
```

What I need is to get the substring (GDNDL380F4) after Name= to column Name and substring (FTT-87) after Type= to column Type.

I tried different approaches with str.extract, find and re.find but for some reason I get wrong result (nan or an empty array). So help is needed.

Comment: Can you write your expected output and share in proper format ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a dictionary from the string and get the items by key

```
s = 'ID=1,Name=GDNDL380F4,Type=FTT-87, Value=GDNDL380F4,Registration Info: Sn = GDNDL380F4, Service Level=Service Level Disabled'
d = dict(item.split("=") for item in s.split(","))
print(d['Name']) # GDNDL380F4
print(d['Type']) # FTT-87
```

Pandas solution:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame([dict(y.split("=") for y in x.strip("' ").split(",")) for x in df['Column']], 
                  index=df.index)
print (df1)
  ID         Name    Type        Value Registration Info: Sn   \
0  1   GDNDL380F4  FTT-87   GDNDL380F4             GDNDL380F4   
1  1  GDNDL4040F4  FTT-87  GDNDL4040F4             GDNDL380F4   
2  1   GDNDL380F5  FTT-87   GDNDL380F5             GDNDL380F4   

            Service Level  
0  Service Level Disabled  
1  Service Level Disabled  
2  Service Level Disabled
```

Comment: I am thinking about it, not sure if not too similar

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way using [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and regex:

```
s = pd.Series('ID=1,Name=GDNDL380F4,Type=FTT-87, Value=GDNDL380F4,Registration Info: Sn = GDNDL380F4, Service Level=Service Level Disabled')
s.str.extract(r'Name=(?P<Name>[^,]+).*?Type=(?P<Type>[^,]+)')
```

[out]

```
         Name    Type
0  GDNDL380F4  FTT-87
```

---

#### Explanation of regex

The `()` are capture groups, these are the parts of the string that will be extracted and returned.

- `?P<Name>` notation will name the groups - it's a convenient way to name your columns
- `Name=([^,]+)` is return any 1 of more consecutive characters that is NOT a comma after the string "Name="
- `.*?` between capture groups is any character (zero or more), with the `?` being a lazy operator - ie. return the least number of characters needed until the next explicit part of the pattern "Type="

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using 'apply' method in python pandas:

```
df[[col.split('=')[0] for col in df['Column'].iloc[0].split(',')]]=df[['Column']].apply(lambda x: [col.split('=')[1] for col in x[0].split(',')],result_type='expand',axis=1)

print(df.iloc[:,1:])
```

Output:

```
  ID         Name    Type        Value Registration Info: Sn   
0  1   GDNDL380F4  FTT-87   GDNDL380F4             GDNDL380F4   
1  1  GDNDL4040F4  FTT-87  GDNDL4040F4             GDNDL380F4   
2  1   GDNDL380F5  FTT-87   GDNDL380F5             GDNDL380F4   

        Service Level  
0  Service Level Disabled  
1  Service Level Disabled  
2  Service Level Disabled
```